# Fresh SSD whilst keeping HDD for storage

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, ssd, hybrid-storage

I am planning on updating from an HDD only system to a SSD (OS + Applications) + HDD (Larger storage of files and some Applications).

I currently have an HDD with Windows 7 on it, but am going to install a fresh installation of Windows 10 on the SSD.

Is it possible to utilise the SSD for the OS whilst still accessing the files on the HDD (even though it still contains Windows 7 OS and file structure therein)? (In other words can I turn an HDD into a storage drive, removing windows 7 without formatting the drive and then recopying the files I would like to keep)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it possible to use the SSD for the OS whilst still accessing the files on the HDD and one thing you can do after setting up the system like this is accessing the HDD and manually erasing Windows, Program Files, Doc&Sett and all the other junk locations windows creates. Then, you're left with your actual useful data. Make sure to move the documents and desktop initial items if you want to do such a clean-up.